# LINQ subexpression doesn't take variable values

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 3 contexts for 3 different servers.  The main application data uses context1 connecting to SQL1.  In a Web API service I get people records asynchronously from context2 connecting to SQL2. It returns 4800+ records. The records are further filtered against the `userFacility` which is a result of a stored procedure from context3 connecting to SQL3.

All approaches work on my development machine with Visual Studio 2019 and IIS Express. When published to the IIS Server on our network only the Approach 2 work. It seems the EF only likes a constant value in the inner expression but not a variable value. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

```cs
IEnumerable<PeopleDTO> people= await aHelper.GetPeopleAsync(aRepository, defaultQuarter, criteria);
/* sample Facility property of People values are
(1V01) (402) Togus, ME
(1V01) (518) Bedford, MA
(1V01) (523) Boston, MA
(1V01) (608) Manchester, NH
(1V01) (631) Central Western Massachusetts
(3V12) (587) Eastern Colorado, CO
*/

List<string> userFacilities = new List<string>(){“608”,”518”,”674”, "587","648"};

/* approach 1 works in VS but not in IIS */
       pepole= pepole.Where(x => userFacilities.Any(y=> x.Facility.Contains(y)));

/* approach 2 works in both in VS and IIS */
       pepole= pepole.Where(x => userFacilities.Any(y=> x.Facility.Contains("587")));


/* Approach 3 works in VS but not in IIS */
List<PeopleDTO> viewablePeople = new List<PeopleDTO>();

foreach (PeopleDTO p in people)
{
    foreach (string y in userFacilities)
    {
        /* doesn't work in IIS but works in VS IIS  Express if y is a constant*/
        if (p.Facility.IndexOf(y) >= 0)
        {
            viewablePeople.Add(p); 
            break;
        }
    }
}

return Ok(viewablePeople);
```

```cs
      public partial class PeopleDTO
      {
        [DisplayName("Facility")]
        public string Facility { get; set; } 

        [DisplayName("District")]
        public string District { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("SSN")]
        public string PTFSSN { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("FSOD SSN")]
        public string FSODSSN { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Fiscal Period")]
        public string FiscalPeriod { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Numeric Fiscal Period")]
        public int FiscalPeriodInt { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Episode")]
        public IEnumerable<EpisodeDTO> Episodes { get; set; }

        public PeopleDTO() {
          Episodes = new List<EpisodeDTO>();
        }
```

Comment: Is there any reason why the constant you use: `"587"` to provide the working examples in IIS is not included in `userFacilities` list (`“608”,”518”,”674”`)?

Comment: Are you querying the same database on the same server from all systems, or are there separate databases on separate servers? If separate, then how were they created: using Migrations, or through other means? Also if separate: are the data in them exactly 100% totally the same? Also if separate: are their `COLLATION` settings the same?

Comment: @Peter B: Good question. The userFacility is retrieved from another database from another server by executing a stored procedure with EF FromSqlRaw() or ExecuteSqlRawAsync(). Then each of the unique Facility of the returned records is added to the local variable userFacility as List<string> type. The context class is generated by EF CORE Power Tools. Please refer to my post for the structure of People. I am just comparing each string in the userFacility list with the People.Facility which has longer string values.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" actually mean? Errors, no results? And which database brand is this?

Answer (score 1):

EF has nothing to do with your data at all, since you just have 2 lists in the computer memory and you don't use db context any more.  So you don't need to use staff like "EF.Functions.Like" that was created to convert linq to t-sql and very inefficient when it is used for something else.

I created a special function GetIt that makes checking  and I am sure it will work everywhere since it is using only c# System.Collections.Generic namespace. I think almost every c# application uses this namespace and I never heard about any problem with it.

Did you check a people list before starting each test? I think your code problem is in  testing. Since you are using peope=people... construction the list is mutates after each testing. And the next approuch uses different data then the previous one had.

Or aHelper.GetPeopleAsync... can also bring the different data when it is using VS and after deployment at IIS.

I don't see any sense to use first 4 approaches since this is not EF. So only makes sense to test approach number 5 one more time, excluding the previous approaches.

This is a demo that was tested in VS. You can try it  at IIS. If it is working there, than the problem is aHelper.GetPeopleAsync function

```
void Main()
{

 people = people.Where(x => GetIt(x.Facility)).ToList();

bool GetIt(string f)
{
    foreach (var uf in userFacilities)
    {
        if ( f.IndexOf(uf) >= 0 ) return true;
    }
    return false;
}


var people  = new List<People> {
new People{ Name="name",Facility="(1V01) (402) Togus, ME"},
new People{ Name="name",Facility="(1V01)(518) Bedford, MA"},
new People{ Name="name",Facility="(1V01)(523) Boston, MA"},
new People{ Name="name",Facility="(1V01)(608) Manchester, NH"},
new People{ Name="name",Facility="(1V01)(631) Central Western Massachusetts"},
new People{ Name="name",Facility="(3V12)(587) Eastern Colorado, CO"}
};

List<string> userFacilities = new List<string>() {"608","518","674", "587","648"};

}

public partial class People
{
    public string Facility { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The people.Facility has string as "abc def 587 efg " or "xyz123 daeada" or "674abcde adakhlkl"

Comment: @Serge: you say "since both of the collections are in memory already .... " but all we see is an IEnumerable, which might as well be a live query object, if I am not mistaken. The question does not reveal any implementation details of `GetPeopleAsync`.

Comment: @PeterB " In a WebAPI service I get people records asynchronously. It RETURNS 4800+ records. I then FURTHER filter the result against the userFacility ..."  .  Plus  Approach 5  certailnly will not work against DB.  But IMHO it is better to wait for PO then start  speculations.

Comment: @Searge:  Yes, the people is an Enumerable.  The userFacility is a List<string>.  Therefore, they are both operated in the client (IIS) memory.  Also the Approach 5 is the basic the same as your GetIt() function.

Answer (score 1):

I think that renaming the variable fac could resolve the issue assuming that is a global variable because I dont see it in the code, the interpolation in the first approach doesnt seem to reference anything

Comment: @Medina, the fac is the variable name following .Any(fac=>....) and in foreach(string fac ....)

Comment: Yes, but the input parameter should be named the same for the expression, unles you are accesing something inside,

try this, just to see if it works
string facility = "xxx";
pepole= pepole.Where(x => userFacilities.Any(fac => x.Facility.Contains(facility)));

Comment: @Medina: yes, I am using fac in the inner expression to refer to the value (facility) in the userFacilities and compare it to the outer expression variable x (people) to see if x contains fac.  Also your expression works when facility = "xxx" as an constant instead of List<string>.